# How to connect existing Automation Account and Log Analytics workspace in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

I have one Log Analytics workspace "demo-law-sea" and one Automation Account "demo-aa-sea" in the same region of Azure. I want to create "Start/Stop VMs during off-hours".

It requests a Log Analytics workspace and an Automation Account. I simply choose "demo-law-sea", but I cannot choose "demo-aa-sea" because they are not linked.

Then I go to both Log Analytics workspace and Automation Account to see if I can link them together. Either one has Related Resource to refer to the other, but they have only unlink button but not link.

To proceed I create a new Automation Account with selected Log Analytics workspace while creating "Start/Stop VMs during off-hours", then I delete the existing Automation Account "demo-aa-sea".

Is there a way to link existing Log Analytic workspace and Automation Account? Any prerequisites? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under your Automation Account in azure portal -> click **Update Management** in the left menu, then you can select the proper Log Analytics.

[image]